# Refactoring variable assignment thru if let block with Enum

Tags: rust, refactoring

I'm working with the code below, which works, but is clearly not a very clever or efficient way to write a value to `res`.

```
let mut res = "";
if let Video(n) = res_info {    // res_info represents reference to &Settings type
    if n.pixel_width > 1920{
         res = "2160p";
    }
    else{
        res = "1080p";
    }
}
```

Printing `res_info` would yield the following:

```
Video(Video { pixel_width: 1920, pixel_height: 1080})
```

The following code seems to be close, however it's not assigning &str to res. I would much prefer a codeblock like this, in which `res` is only declared once.

```
let res = if let Video(n) = res_info {
    if n.pixel_width > 1920 {
        "2160p";
    }
    else{
        "1080p";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [unit](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.unit.html) documentation

`The semicolon ; can be used to discard the result of an expression at the end of a block, making the expression (and thus the block) evaluate to ()`

Removing the semicolon should stop value from being discarded so the `&str` is resolved from the `if` blocks.

```rust
let res = if let Video(n) = res_info {
    if n.pixel_width > 1920{
         "2160p"
    } else{
        "1080p"
    }
}else{
    panic!("res_info is not a Video")
};
```

or with a match statement might be cleaner

```rust
let res = match res_info {
    Video(n) if n.pixel_width > 1920 => "2160p",
    Video(n) => "1080p",
    _ => panic!("res_info is not a Video")
};
```